# Centering curved text on a line in an SVG

Tags: svg

I have created a half-circle path as an SVG in illustrator, I want to center the text along this path and the text will be dynamic so I basically need the text to always start in the center (bottom most point of the curve). I have this most of the way there but the text is still off-kilter a bit. The properties I have tried are `x="50%" y="50%"`, `dominant-baseline="middle"`, and `text-anchor="middle"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 2" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <g data-name="Layer 1">
    <path d="M0 0h500v500H0z" style="fill:none"/>
    <path id="curved-text" d="M63 250c0 103.55 83.95 187.5 187.5 187.5S438 353.55 438 250" style="stroke:#000;fill:none"/>
    <text font-size="30" fill="#000000" letter-spacing="2" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="bold" x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curved-text">This is my centered text</textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The text ends up being more to the left of the bottom anchor than it should be.

Comment: Use `text-anchor="middle"` for the text and remove `x="50%" y="50%"`. Also for the <textPath> use `startOffset = "50%"`

Comment: @enxaneta Brilliant, thank you! Please add as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [startOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/startOffset) attribute on the textPath and give it the value 50%.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 2" viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="height:220px">
  <g data-name="Layer 1">
    <path d="M0 0h500v500H0z" style="fill:none"/>
    <path id="curved-text" d="M63 250c0 103.55 83.95 187.5 187.5 187.5S438 353.55 438 250" style="stroke:#000;fill:none" />
    <text font-size="30" fill="#000000" letter-spacing="2" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="bold" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
      <textPath startOffset="50%" href="#curved-text">This is my centered text</textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```